# Cannot Show Data

Tags: php, post, get

I Have Problem Like This
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ltP.png)

And This The Code

```
    <?php 
        if(isset(($_POST['nama'] || $_POST['alamat']))
        {
            echo "Nama : ". $_POST['nama']. "<br>";
            echo "Alamat : ". $_POST['alamat']. "<br>";
        }
    ?>
    <?php 
       if(isset($_GET['input']))
        {
            echo "Your Input : ". $_GET['input']. "<br>";
        }
    ?>
```

Can Help Me

Comment: put your sction in your form tag. form method post and submit button type submit

Comment: @PHP Regarding [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24172253). Why are you modifying code by adding something to what did not exist? I am rejecting the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It`s work for me

```
<?php 
                if(isset($_POST['nama']) || isset($_POST['alamat']))
                {
                    echo "Nama : ". $_POST['nama']. "<br>";
                    echo "Alamat : ". $_POST['alamat']. "<br>";
                }
            ?>
            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['input']))
                {
                    echo "Your Input : ". $_GET['input']. "<br>";
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :)

```
            <?php 
                if(@$_POST['nama'] || @$_POST['alamat'])
                {
                    echo "Nama : ". $_POST['nama']. "<br>";
                    echo "Alamat : ". $_POST['alamat']. "<br>";
                }
            ?>
            <?php 
                if(@$_GET['input'])
                {
                    echo "Your Input : ". $_GET['input']. "<br>";
                }
            ?>
```

it must work